# Getting a compiler error using Visual Studio, 2019

Tags: c++

A segment of code shown below gives a compiler error when 3 arguments are provided for the function getline. getline(a,b); works, getline(a,b,c); does not work. Yet both of these forms are valid per C++
definitions. In the later case, parameter c would be the character when the function would stop reading, i.e. "\n". Not sure why this is.

```
input_file.open("Future Appointment Data File", ios::in);
//Print Header
cout << "Name" << "                " << "Date" << "       " << "Purpose" << "                       " 
<< "Time" << "    " << "Confirmation" << "  " << "Comment" << "\n";
do
  {
     input_file.getline(InData, 120);
     cout << InData;
     cout << "\n";
  } while (!input_file.eof());
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: you are using getline wrong , refer https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: @Mouse https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline

Comment: Present a [mcve] please stfark.

Comment: Please add more details @stfark

Answer (score 1):

Your question suggests you are providing a *string* (enclosed in double-quotes) for the 3rd argument, when it requires a *character* (enclosed in single quotes).

Answer (score -1):

you are using getline wrong please correct the syntax.

[getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: A very unhelpful, almost link-only answer. _How_ is it being used wrong? What would the correct syntax be?

Comment: My mistake ,I thought , InData to be a stringstream.

Comment: Thanks Scott, used getline(A,B,C), C with single quote rather than double, works great, my bad, Sid